# OpenCV findContours are in reverse order

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Why the contour is in reverse order? I use the RETR_EXTERNAL flag for contours hierarchy for detect only the external contours

_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(connected.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

[image]

For example my my output is r,e B, why in reverse order?

Comment: The only order that you can depend on in `findContours` is the hierarchy. You cannot depend on which blob will be detected first.

Comment: But I use the RETR_EXTERNAL flag so all contours are on the same hierarchy.

Comment: @zindarod The hierarchy doesn't determine the positional parameters of a contour, it specifies the parent-child relationship between contours.

Comment: @Razvan There is a wonderful post [HERE](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/04/20/sorting-contours-using-python-and-opencv/) please have a look

Comment: @JeruLuke I didn't say that it does. I said that the hierarchy is the only ordering that the `findContours` function provides. The OP was assuming that just because the *B* character was positioned first, it would be detected first, which it may or may not.

Comment: @zindarod Well I thought you took it the other way round, that's why I posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* use some heuristic to sort the contours.  The following example uses the minimum x coordinate of each contour to sort them:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('BB7eu.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

contours.sort(key=lambda c: np.min(c[:,:,0]))

for i in range(len(contours)):
    cur = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    cv2.drawContours(cur, contours, i, (0,0,255), -1)
    cv2.putText(cur, "i=%d" % i, (140,90), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, (0,255,255), 1)
    cv2.imshow("img", cur)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

You'll see that the contours are highlighted "in order": B,e,r.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: making use of numpy, fast and efficient +1 !

Comment: Thank you for the response, but why findContours highlighted in reverse order? Which is the explanation?

Comment: You'd have to study [the paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=6230298349355764762&hl=en&as_sdt=0,39&as_vis=1) to answer that, but I will say that without sorting I don't get them in reverse order, but rather: e,r,B.